# Filling an array of arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

This is the code I've:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int a[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int array_grande[3][8];

    for(int m=0; m<3; m++) {
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
                array_grande[m] = a[i];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've declared array_grande as an array with 3 positions and each position of 8 ints, so what I want to have is an array of arrays.

```
array_grande = {{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}}
```

The code I made is not working, I suppose it's because of the second index of `array_grande`. Can anyone give me a hand? I would like to mantain the code as it is as much as possible. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code does not compile with a C compiler. Tag changed.

Comment: change `array_grande[m] = a[i];` to `array_grande[m][i] = a[i];`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> array_grande[m] = a[i];
> ```

You, probably, want

```
array_grande[m][i] = a[i];
```

Or you can use function `copy` from `algorithm` header:

```
std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), array_grande[m]);
```

Another way is using `std::array`:

```
std::array<int, 8> a{{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}};
std::array<std::array<int, 8>, 3> array_grande;

for(auto& elem: array_grande)
    elem = a;
```

Or, simpler:

```
std::array<int, 8> a{{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}};
std::array<std::array<int, 8>, 3> array_grande{{a, a, a}};
```

Comment: I've changed it to `array_grande[m][i] = a[i];` but when I'm trying to loop to print the items 

`for (int p=0; p<3; p++) printf(" %d ", array_grande[p]);`

It shows strange values: `1606415760  1606415792  1606415824`

Comment: `printf(" %d ", array_grande[p])` - will print address of array, not elements. You should iterate over `array_grande[p]` too.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to achieve your goal:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int a[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int array_grande[3][8];
    int array_grande_2[3][8] = { {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7} };
    int array_grande_3[3][8];
    int array_grande_4[3][8];

    for(int m=0; m<3; m++) {
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
                array_grande[m][i] = a[i];
        }
    }

    for(int m=0; m<3; m++) {
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
                array_grande_3[m][i] = i;
        }
    }

    for(int m=0; m<3; m++) {
        memcpy(&array_grande_4[m], a, 8 * sizeof(int));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your inner assignment:

```
array_grande[m] = a[i];
```

You're assigning an `int` (`a[i]`) to an array or pointer to int (`array_grande[m]`). You just need to change it as follows:

```
array_grande[m][i] = a[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int a[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int array_grande[3][8];

    for(int m=0; m<3; m++) {
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
                array_grande[m][i] = a[i];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

you need to add [i] inside the arrey as it is a 2 d array.

by array_grande[m] it will still be a 1 d array so you need to add [] so as to make tham of same dimension

Answer (score 1):

```
int a[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
```

`a[i]` represents one int like `0` `1` etc

```
int array_grande[3][8];
```

You create a 2D array of int.

```
array_grande[0] -> | | | | | | | | | 
array_grande[1] -> | | | | | | | | |
array_grande[2] -> | | | | | | | | |
```

`array_grande[i]` already has an address since its a 1D array. You can't assign `a[i]` to it.

You need to refer to location within each row to store the value.

```
for(int m=0; m<3; m++) 
{
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) 
    {
            array_grande[m][i] = a[i];
    }
}
```

i.e. `*(array_grande[m] + i) = a[i]` get the row and advance to `i`<sup>th</sup> location